# How to send data from snowflake to an API endpoint?

Tags: api, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a list of data obtained with a query in Snowflake and I need to publish this list to an API Endpoint (json format). Is there a function or short method in Snowflake to send data directly to an endpoint without using other tools in between?

Comment: Please add more context. Do you have code to show how you would this normally without Snowflake? It's unclear what kind of "endpoint" you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake does not offer an API that serves query results, but if you already have API service, then there exist many connectors (e.g. JDBC and Python) to connect to Snowflake, run queries and retrieve the results.

If you like to live dangerously, that can be as simple as the following from Bash, the accessible via http://127.0.0.1:8000/cgi-bin/data.py:

```
pip3 install pyarrow==3.0.0
pip3 install snowflake-connector-python
mkdir cgi-bin
touch cgi-bin/data.py
chmod +x cgi-bin/data.py
cat << EOF > cgi-bin/data.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import snowflake.connector
conn = snowflake.connector.connect( user='', password='', account='')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select current_timestamp;")
print("Content-Type: application/json\n")
print(cur.fetch_pandas_all().to_json())
EOF
python3 -m http.server --cgi 8000
```